# How to get PushNotifications from firebase when Android app is closed

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

Not long ago I started to learn FCM, I checked the tutorial on YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w2q2D6mR7g
(there is an GitHub link in the description). This android app and notifications works perfect only when app is open or in foreground mode. When I killing my app, notifications not works.

I need to get notifications when my app is closed. For example: telegram notifications(It works always).

I tried to set an autostart mode in settings of my app, but can I do it without autostart?

I think the notification is not arrive because I send it by  token, which refreshing every app restart:

> ```
>     public App()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>
>         MainPage = new MainPage();
>
>         CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Subscribe("all");
>         CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += Current_OnTokenRefresh;
>     }
>
>     private void Current_OnTokenRefresh(object source, FirebasePushNotificationTokenEventArgs e)
>     {
>         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Token: {e.Token}");
>     }
> ```

Comment: What device are you using? Some android devices like Oneplus and Oppo have a setting to prevent any background activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the following scenarios when managing the notification:

- Status of the application when the push notification reaches the device (foreground, background, or closed).
- The type of operating system, that is, on iOS or Android.
- The types of payloads that make up the message sent by the message server.

In the following article you can see a flow chart that the notifications follow: https://yaircarreno.medium.com/do-you-know-the-push-notification-flow-7eb67c7fa3f7

Example of message with notification and data payload (specifying activity that receives the notification):

```
{
   "notification":{
      "title":"title",
      "body":"text"
   },
   "data":{
      "title":"title",
      "body":"text",
      "score":"4.5"
   },
   "android":{
      "notification":{
         "priority":"high",
         "sound":"default",
         "clickAction":".PushReceiverActivity"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: good, So I need onMessageRecieved(), can you give examples, how can I use this void?

Comment: Sure, in this public repository you can see an example: https://github.com/yaircarreno/Push-Notifications-Handbook-Android/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/yaircarreno/pushnotificationshandbook/PushNotificationHandbookService.java

Comment: thx, but if you have examples with Xamarin, It will be the best way)

Comment: Remember, if you only have a data payload configured, then the notifications will receive by onMessageReceived. But, if you have click_action configured, then, the notifications will be received by onCreated method in that specific Activity. I updated the answer with an example of the payload sending by server.